# Same PowerShell Code Works as Seperate File, Not as Function

Tags: function, powershell, object, return

I've written some PowerShell code that executes as expected when isolated as a discrete .ps1 file.

```
$unredacted = @()
$redacted = @()

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path \test\1234 -Filter *.tif | Sort-Object -Property Name

$files -match '(.*)_redacted' | ForEach-Object {
    $base = $_.BaseName
    $unredacted += ($base.substring(0, $base.Length - 9) + $_.Extension)
    $redacted += $_.Name
}

$i = 0
$redacted_filesets = $unredacted | ForEach-Object {
    $unredactedCurrent = $_
    $redactedCurrent = $redacted[$i]
    $properties = @{
        Unredacted = $unredactedCurrent
        Redacted   = $redactedCurrent
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
    $i++
}

Return $redacted_filesets
```

However, when I place this code into a function library file and make the path a parameter, so I can call it from other places, it doesn't return anything anymore. When I've done this same process in the past, I've been able to get the expected return.

```
function Find-Redacted-Filesets {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Find pairs of unredacted and redacted files of the same item. 
        .DESCRIPTION
        Find all the tif files in the path and sort them by name, identify the redacted files and add filenames for redacted and unredacted files to arrays. Use the arrays to create a PSObject with all the redacted filesets.
        .PARAMETER path
        The path to the directory holding files to scan for redacted filesets.
        .EXAMPLE
        Find-Redacted-Filesets -path \test\1234
        .INPUTS
        System.String
        .OUTPUTS
        System.Object
    #>
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $path
    )

    $unredacted = @()
    $redacted = @()

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.tif -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property Name

    $files -match '(.*)_redacted' | ForEach-Object {
        $base = $_.BaseName
        $unredacted += ($base.substring(0, $base.Length - 9) + $_.Extension)
        $redacted += $_.Name
    }

    $i = 0
    $redacted_filesets = $unredacted | ForEach-Object {
        $unredactedCurrent = $_
        $redactedCurrent = $redacted[$i]
        $properties = @{
            Unredacted = $unredactedCurrent
            Redacted   = $redactedCurrent
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
        $i++
    }
    Return $redacted_filesets
}
```

And to call it from within another .ps1 script: `. \util\lib.ps1 Find-Redacted-Filesets -path \test\1234`.

I can't figure out the difference here or why I'm not getting a returned object when supply the same path to the function. What am I missing?

Comment: `.  \util\lib.ps1 Find-Redacted-Filesets -path \test\1234` -- is this meant to be on two lines? because as one line it will not work

Comment: Also, get yourself out of the habit of using `return $var` -- just use `$var` instead. Anything not explicitly captured is returned to the caller. This could bite you in the future. Restrain yourself to use empty `return` to leave a function early only.

Comment: @x0n Yes, I did intend for that to be a single line for this example. In some scripts, I've had to keep it on one line, but not always. Generally, I would just use dot notation to pull in the external library at the top and then call the function as needed. Just tested as two lines and it works as expected! I don't understand enough about why I need to keep it on one line sometimes and two lines others, but just happy it's working! Thanks for the tip about return too. If you want to supply an answer below I'll mark it correct or answer myself and refer to your comment if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@x0n had the answer in a comment above.
`. \util\lib.ps1 Find-Redacted-Filesets -path \test\1234` had to be broken up into two lines.

```
. \util\lib.ps1
Find-Redacted-Filesets -path \test\1234
```

Comment: It can still be one line, you just have to add a semicolon after `lib.ps1`.